Is there a scenario where the client's data is lost, even when it gets success acknowledgement?
In RAFT, assume we have 5 nodes a,b,c,d & e and that "a" is the leader.
A client connected to "a", sent a write (doing non-idempotent operation OP1) request to "a". "a" sends it to the followers using AppendEntries.entries[]. Only "b" and "c" receive this update and acknowledges after saving the update. Assume, this is somehow not yet received by "d" and "e".
"a" sees that it is accepted by the majority and responds success ack back to the client and commits the write to its state machine. It schedules AppendEntries message with updated prevLogIndex to that of index of this new write entry in the log, so that followers also apply it to their state machine. But assume, before this request message is received by any of the nodes, both "a" and "b" went down and the message is also lost, maybe due to partition.
Now, "c" has the uncommitted changes, and "d" and "e" do not have the change. With this, will the written data by the client be lost? Will "c" becomes the leader in this case and tries to commit the change? If so, how does it know "a" had received majority? May be "b" also had not got the first AppendEntries.entries[] message.
To give an example:
Client writes OP1
Scenario 1:
    [A] : [OP1 term=1]

    [B] : [OP1 term=1]

    [C] : [OP1 term=1]

    [D] :

    [E] :

A gets a majority and commits to its state machine and responds with a success to client. A & B gets partitioned. C is now the leader. Will C replicate and commit OP1 in this case?
Scenario 2:
    [A] : [OP1 term=1]

    [B] : 

    [C] : [OP1 term=1]

    [D] :

    [E] :

A could replicate to only C. Then both A & B are partitioned. A responds with a failure notification to the client.  C is now the leader. will C replicate and commit x=x+1 in this case? Even if it replicates, it cannot send any response back to the client.
If C gets a new request from a client OP2, will it overwrite the uncommitted log and replicate?
Scenario 1:
    [C] : [OP1 term=1][OP2 term=2]

    [D] : [OP1 term=1][OP2 term=2]

    [E] : [OP1 term=1][OP2 term=2]

Scenario 2:
    [C] : [OP2 term=2]

    [D] : [OP2 term=2]

    [E] : [OP2 term=2]


After going through the RAFT paper multiple times, I got the answer. My question is slightly in-accurate.
The guarantee of RAFT is: If the leader could replicate the entry to the majority, including itself, the entry can be considered committed and is guaranteed to be persisted, even if the leader goes down. A success message could be sent back to the client. If the leader could not replicate the majority, the leader will keep on trying to replicate the majority. But it will be committed only if the entry appears in the log of the majority.
In my example (Scenario 1), when nodes A & B goes down, among C, D and E, C has the longest log and it is guaranteed to be the leader. C will replicate the OP1 to D & E. It will get committed eventually when some other request comes in the leader's current term.
In scenario 2, when the OP1 is not in majority, the entry may or may not get committed. For example, if both A & C goes down, there wont be any history of OP1. Between B, D & E, other entries may get committed and this will eventually override OP1. But if only A goes down, C will emerge as the leader and replicate the entry to B, D & E.

That means we can still lost uncommitted entry in scenario 2.
